# Open source software development collaboration

Tags: web-applications, open-source, project-management, wiki

I'm looking for a hosted web platform that will help me build and maintain an open source project.  Things I feel are important to have:

- Wiki area for documentation about our project where members can edit and visitors can view
- Forum for visitors to ask questions and members can collaborate
- Project management features like tasks to organize development
- Blog where select members can post
- FAQ (maybe not so important)

Would also be nice to maybe have integrations with GitHub, GoToWebinar (auto-setup and notifications of meetings?), diagram tool like Gliffy, etc.

The important thing is that everything should be publicly visible.  What do the good, productive open source projects use to manage their efforts and website?

***UPDATE***: I want to make it clear I am **happy** to pay for a platform that makes it easier to run an open source project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/) is what you are looking for?

Comment: Looks very interesting, playing with it now.

Comment: This does everything I asked for, so I'm definitely crediting you with the answer.  It's just visually poor looking.  In my chrome browser, the wiki pages look strange with a very wide sidebar and text that touches borders...  Feels a little unprofessional.  I'm sure it's a great service though, this is exactly what I wanted.